# What is the use of portable shell scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, portability

I usually write my scripts in bash. I tell other people to run them in bash, and I use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as the shebang line.

When I read about shell scripting I often find comments with suggestions of "portable" solutions that do not use "bashisms". A portable shell script seems to be a one that can be run in any Bourne Shell derivative, eg. bash, ksh, or csh.

To me this seems a bit weird. Why would you not know what shell you run your script in? So my question is: **What is the actual use of portable shell scripts?** If you feel like using bash features, why not simply use bash?

I assume that there are common situations when portability is required, for why would it otherwise be mentioned so often? Perhaps certain environments require portability for historical reasons - I don't know - but I'm interested in finding out what these environments are.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

My conclusions from your answers and comments (thank you!):

- You may need to avoid newer bash features because they may not be available in all bash versions, and some computers will have old versions installed.
- An installer script should be runnable on computers you don't control. Not all Unix-like OSes come with bash by default. On the contrary the POSIX shell is nearly universally available, therefore it provides better reach than bash.
- You may need to run a script on 1000 computers, but you don't want to (or can't) install bash everywhere. A POSIX shell is probably available.
- You may not even be able to install bash on the computer you like. For example this might be due to lack of administration rights, the lack of a bash package for the platform, or the lack of resources like in a "bare-bones" computer. Again, a POSIX shell is probably available.
- In some environments you can't assume the shell to be anything more than a POSIX shell, for example in System V style init scripts. (Is this correct?)

**Bottom line: You can't always use bash anywhere you like, but a POSIX shell is likely already there.**

Comment: Imagine you have to run a script every night on 1000 servers you administrate. In case some are old Solaris (for example), certain `bashisms` will fail.

Comment: `... answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.`

Comment: csh is not a Bourne shell derivative.

Comment: @devnull While answers to this post may be opinionated, I have specific experience with this (even across bash versions). You don't have to start out on the defense writing scripts for any version of any shell, but over time you get habits that makes sure you avoid spending time on such pitfalls. I've often chosen shell scripting over other languages to be portable in the first place...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why would you not know what shell you run your script in?

- You are writing an installer script that must run on an unknown machine.
- You are writing a single script that will work with multiple known shells.
- Not all `bash` features work the same even across different versions of `bash` (see the `compat31`, `compat32`, `compat40`, `compat41` options).

Some common examples of non-`bash` usage:

- `dash` is the system shell for Debian and Ubuntu
- Mac OS X continues to ship with `bash` 3.2 instead of 4.x
- Solaris uses, I believe, a version of `ksh`
- `bash` needs to be installed separately on FreeBSD systems.

Answer (score 1):

This would be for *Bourne Shell* compatibility itself, so that the script can run on a bare-bones machine that simply has only `sh` or *any* other machine that has *any* (Bourne compatible) shell(s).  You'd obviously *only* do this for full and complete **compatibility**.